# Why all images become invalid after Cleaning the project?

Tags: ios, xcode

The console says :

> Could not load the "xxx" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier

And all my `imageviews` become blank.

How do I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You did rebuild? Do the images still exist in the project? Worst case just restore the last working version from your Git repository. Worst^2 case restore from your remote repository (Bitbucket, GitHub or other). Worse^3 case  restore from your Time Machine backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For people who caught with the same problem:

I eventually copy all the files to a new project and everything works as charm. 
So I guess it was caused by some unknown caching bugs in Xcode and Simulator. Hopes this would help.

Thanks to @Rajat and @rejupal

Comment: If you finally solved your problem from any answer, then do not forgot to upvote & accept that answer, as it treats as encouragement for other person to help in future. Hope you got my point :)

Answer (score 0):

While adding the images to your project a dialog box is opened, click

> Select "Create groups for any added folders" which Xcode generally select was not the case, & check whether it is added to your Target or not, the target checkbox should be clicked.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a wired caching bug from xcode that the xib file wont get updated. Please delete "xxx" image and reference corresponding from the nib file. Now rename the "xxx" image to another name, copy to the project folder and add to the project. Reconnect to the nib. Clean the project and run.

Make sure that the image type is .jpg or .png

Hope this will help you.